# python regular express how to take a value that could or could not be proceeded by "&page=2"

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

These are the possible strings i might face

> http://bla bla bla/?another bla bla bla
>
> http://bla bla bla/?another bla bla bla&page=3

#### My question

I want to take

> http://bla bla bla/?another bla bla bla

#### What I tried

```
re.match("(.*)^&page=+\d",value).group(1)
```

where `value` is a prameter that has the value of the string.

but I get :

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I know the reason (which is the regular expression is wrong), but I don't know the solution

Comment: remove `^` from the regex, move `+` after `\d` (now it would match multiple `=`; though actually it is not strictly needed).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that does help in the second sentence, but not the first one, (and the reason is the first one doesn't have &page=3)

Comment: If regex does not match, it returns `None`. That you need to check. Again, there is nothing to remove in the first one.

Comment: So you want to full url unless it has &page=something? then just before the&?

Comment: Someone said that the problem can never be reproduced :) that is really funny,

Comment: @joelgoldstick I want the url *without* the Page=number, some urls does have that *page=number*, some don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use regular expressions here it can be done by simple application of string manipulation.

```
value = 'http://bla bla bla/?another bla bla bla&page=3'
index =  value.find(r'&page=')
if index > 0:
    result = value[:index]
else:
    result = value
```

Comment: what is "s" ? do you mean "value" ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are parsing urls, use dedicated parsing library, namely [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse).

```
import urlparse
my_url = "http://domain.com/some/address?some=data&page=3&another=param"
p = urlparse.urlparse(my_url) # ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='domain.com', path='/some/address', params='', query='some=data&page=3&another=param', fragment='')
new_url = urlparse.ParseResult(p.scheme, p.netloc, p.path, p.params, '', p.fragment)  # remove query path
valid_url = urlparse.urlunparse(parsed_url)  # http://domain.com/some/address
```

Obviously, you'll need to tweak this solution for your real-case usage, since mock data presented in question are not sufficient to know how url should be parsed in unambiguous way.